# Use regex backreferences to create array

Tags: python, regex

I'm not really sure of the best way to summarize this in one sentence for the title, so please edit it to make it clearer if necessary.

I have a list of strings (parsed from a Web page) of the format

```
"\tLocation\tNext Available Appointment: Date\n"
```

I'd like to turn this into a list of lists, each with the format

```
["Location", "Date"]
```

I know what regular expression I would use, but I don't know how to use the results.

(For reference, here's the regular expression that would find what I want.)

```
^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$
```

I found how to match regexes against text, but not how to extract the results to something else. I am new to Python, though, so I acknowledge that I probably missed something while searching.

Comment: use the above regex in `re.findall`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function within a list comprehension :

```
import re
[re.findall(r'^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$',i) for i in my_list]
```

For example :

```
>>> my_list=["\tLocation\tNext Available Appointment: Date\n","\tLocation2\tNext Available Appointment: Date2\n"]
>>> [re.findall(r'^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$',i) for i in my_list]
[[('Location', 'Date')], [('Location2', 'Date2')]]
```

You can also use `re.search()` with `groups()` method :

```
>>> [re.search(r'^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$',i).groups() for i in my_list]
[('Location', 'Date'), ('Location2', 'Date2')]
```

Note that the advantage of `re.search` here is that you'll get a list of tuples instead of list of list of tuples (with `findall()`).

Comment: I didn't know about tuples. I think a list of tuples makes more sense than a list of lists.

Comment: @stephenwade Yeah,i suggest the second one,myself!

Comment: This is literally my first Python script. I had something to do and I decided I'd try to do it in Python instead of Bash.

Comment: @stephenwade Be sure that your choice is correct! keep using python and enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a flat list with

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$')
test_str = "    Location    Next Available Appointment: Date\n"
print [item for sublist in re.findall(p, test_str) for item in sublist]
```

Output:

```
['Location', 'Date']
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/VbW3Gs)

**EDIT**:

Or, you can make use of `finditer`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?m)^\t(.*)\t.*: (.*)$')
test_str = "    Location    Next Available Appointment: Date\n  Location1   Next Available Appointment: Date1\n"
print [(x.group(1), x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

Output od [another demo](https://ideone.com/8BsZFF):

```
[('Location', 'Date'), ('Location1', 'Date1')]
```